# Einstein Bot: Capture customer's cookie value and pass to the Live Transcript object

Tags: apex, einstein, einstein-chatbot

as the title suggests, I am trying to capture a cookie value from the customer and expose it to the Einstein Bot so that it can be stored in a field within the LiveChatTranscript object. So far I have created the custom field and within the embedded chat code I have added:

embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
"label": "visitor URL",
"value": window.location.href,
"displayToAgent": true,
"transcriptFields" : ["visitor_url__c"]
}

This is returning the page the customer is on currently. Instead I am trying to get the value of a cookie from the user that they clicked from a marketing email to land on the website. The website is already designed to capture that URL in its cookies.
With my current code, if the customer switches to a different page before using the bot, I am losing the URL they used to come to the website. How can I expose the bot to that specific cookie value?